# Why do try!() and ? not compile when used in a function that doesn't return Option or Result?

Tags: rust

Why does this code not compile?

```
use std::{fs, path::Path};

fn main() {
    let dir = Path::new("../FileSystem");

    if !dir.is_dir() {
        println!("Is not a directory");
        return;
    }

    for item in try!(fs::read_dir(dir)) {
        let file = match item {
            Err(e) => {
                println!("Error: {}", e);
                return;
            }
            Ok(f) => f,
        };

        println!("");
    }

    println!("Done");
}
```

This is the error I get

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:11:17
   |
11 |     for item in try!(fs::read_dir(dir)) {
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected (), found enum `std::result::Result`
   |
   = note: expected type `()`
              found type `std::result::Result<_, _>`
   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate (in Nightly builds, run with -Z external-macro-backtrace for more info)
```

I also tried the question mark operator:

```
for item in fs::read_dir(dir)? {
```

Which had a different error:

```
error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be used in a function that returns `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `std::ops::Try`)
  --> src/main.rs:11:17
   |
11 |     for item in fs::read_dir(dir)? {
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot use the `?` operator in a function that returns `()`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::ops::Try` is not implemented for `()`
   = note: required by `std::ops::Try::from_error`
```

Previous versions of Rust had a similar error about `std::ops::Carrier`

Should I avoid `try!()` and `?`? What is the best way to handle errors? Mostly I do it like this:

```
match error_prone {
    Err(e) => {
        println!("Error: {}", e);
        return;
    },
    Ok(f) => f,
};
```

But if I have to use that in a `for` loop, it's a complete mess

```
for i in match error_prone {
    // match code
} {
    // loop code
}
```

Comment: `try!` is a macro that `return`s `Err`s automatically. You can't use it in `main` because `main` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Aaaahn that explains a lot.. Thank you for that! And how would I handle the errors in this specific case? Without having to resort to the weird `for match` syntax mentioned above

Comment: [See also.](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2014/11/6/error-handling-in-rust/) In general the lazy route is to stick your code in some wrapper function that you call from `main` that returns `Result<T, Box<Error>>` and then `unwrap` or handle that in `main`.

Comment: `unwrap` is basically `panic` on error right?

Comment: `println!("{}", path.unwrap().path().file_name().unwrap().to_str().unwrap());`  really? :p

Comment: What type is `path` there?

Comment: Since all the functions return Result<something> I have a hard time knowing what to answer to your question. But the [file is on Github](https://github.com/azerupi/rust-learn/blob/master/FileSystem/dircontent.rs) It's the result of [read_dir](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.read_dir.html)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`try!` is a macro that returns `Err`s automatically; `?` is syntax that does mostly the same thing, but it works with any type that implements the [`Try`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Try.html) trait.

As of [Rust 1.22.0](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1220-2017-11-22), `Option` implements `Try`, so it can be used with `?`. Before that, `?` could only be used in functions that return a `Result`. `try!` continues to only work with `Result`s.

As of [Rust 1.26.0](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/48453), `main` is allowed to return a value that implements `Termination`. Before that, it doesn't return any value.

#### As of Rust 1.26.0

Your original code works if you mark `main` as returning a `Result` and then return `Ok(())` in all the "success" cases:

```
use std::{fs, io, path::Path};

fn main() -> Result<(), io::Error> {
    let dir = Path::new("../FileSystem");

    if !dir.is_dir() {
        println!("Is not a directory");
        return Ok(());
    }

    for item in fs::read_dir(dir)? {
        let file = match item {
            Err(e) => {
                println!("Error: {}", e);
                return Ok(());
            }
            Ok(f) => f,
        };

        println!("");
    }

    println!("Done");
    Ok(())
}
```

#### Before that

This is how you might transform your code to use `?`:

```
use std::{error::Error, fs, path::Path};

fn print_dir_contents() -> Result<String, Box<Error>> {
    let dir = Path::new("../FileSystem");

    if !dir.is_dir() {
        return Err(Box::from("Is not a directory!"));
    }

    for entry in fs::read_dir(dir)? {
        let path = entry?.path();
        let file_name = path.file_name().unwrap();
        println!("{}", file_name.to_string_lossy());
    }

    Ok("Done".into())
}

fn main() {
    match print_dir_contents() {
        Ok(s) => println!("{}", s),
        Err(e) => println!("Error: {}", e.to_string()),
    }
}
```

There's a lot of error handling here that you might not expect - other languages don't tend to require it! But they exist in other languages - Rust just makes you know it. Here are the errors:

> ```
> entry?
> ```

IO errors can happen during iteration.

> ```
> path.file_name().unwrap()
> ```

Not all paths have file names. We can `unwrap` this because `read_dir` won't give us a path without a file name.

> ```
> file_name.to_string_lossy()
> ```

You can also `to_str` and throw an error, but it's nicer to do this. This error exists because not all file names are valid Unicode.

`try!` and `?` throw errors into the return value, converting them to `Box::Error`. It's actually more reasonable to return an amalgamated error of all the things that can go wrong. Luckily `io::Error` is just the right type:

```
use std::io;

// ...

fn print_dir_contents() -> Result<String, io::Error> {
    // ...

    if !dir.is_dir() {
        return Err(io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, "Is not a directory!"));
    }

    // ...
}
```

Frankly, though, this check is already in `fs::read_dir`, so you can actually just remove the `if !dis.is_dir` altogether:

```
use std::{fs, io, path::Path};

fn print_dir_contents() -> Result<String, io::Error> {
    let dir = Path::new("../FileSystem");

    for entry in fs::read_dir(dir)? {
        let path = entry?.path();
        let file_name = path.file_name().unwrap();
        println!("{}", file_name.to_string_lossy());
    }

    Ok("Done".into())
}

fn main() {
    match print_dir_contents() {
        Ok(s) => println!("{}", s),
        Err(e) => println!("Error: {}", e.to_string()),
    }
}
```

Comment: To make it work for other type of errors with `?` operator, I needed to change to `fn main() -> Result<(), Box<std::error::Error>>> {` Read more https://blog.burntsushi.net/rust-error-handling/#the-real-try-macro-operator

Answer (score 7):

The [ques_in_main RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1937-ques-in-main.md) got merged recently. Once it's [completed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/43301), the syntax in the question will indeed compile just fine and work as intended, provided the `try!()` calls are replaced with the `?` operator.

Answer (score 3):

As of Rust 1.26, Rust supports a return value from main(), and thus supports the use of the error-check operator `?` (or equivalently the `try!()` macro) in `main()` when `main()` is defined to return a `Result`:

```
extern crate failure;
use failure::Error;
use std::fs::File;

type Result<T> = std::result::Result<T, Error>;

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let mut _file = File::open("foo.txt")?; // does not exist; returns error
    println!("the file is open!");
    Ok(())
}
```

The above compiles and returns a file not found error (assuming `foo.txt` does not exist in the local path).

[Rust playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=66e0c9300c6db17e314819bdaf9b4516&version=stable&mode=debug)

Answer (score 1):

Veedrac's answer helped me too, although the OP's question is slightly different. While reading the Rust documentation, I saw this snippet:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;

let mut file = File::open("foo.txt")?;
let mut contents = String::new();
file.read_to_string(&mut contents)?;
assert_eq!(contents, "Hello, world!");
```

Though in the Rust Book they point out the centrality of the main function, if you run this inside it you'll get a similar error. If you wrap the code inside a function handling the errors the aforementioned snippet works:

```
use std::error::Error;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;

fn print_file_content() -> Result<String, Box<Error>> {
    let mut f = File::open("foo.txt")?;
    let mut contents = String::new();

    f.read_to_string(&mut contents)?;

    println!("The content: {:?}", contents);

    Ok("Done".into())
}

fn main() {
    match print_file_content() {
        Ok(s) => println!("{}", s),
        Err(e) => println!("Error: {}", e.to_string()),
    }
}
```

P.S. I'm learning Rust so these snippets are not intended as good Rust coding :)