# How to check whether a path exists?

Tags: rust

The choice seems to be between `std::fs::PathExt` and `std::fs::metadata`, but the latter is suggested for the time being as it is more stable. Below is the code I have been working with as it is based off the docs:

```
use std::fs;

pub fn path_exists(path: &str) -> bool {
    let metadata = try!(fs::metadata(path));
    assert!(metadata.is_file());
}
```

However, for some odd reason `let metadata = try!(fs::metadata(path))` still requires the function to return a `Result<T,E>` even though I simply want to return a boolean as shown from `assert!(metadata.is_file())`.

Even though there will probably be a lot of changes to this soon enough, how would I bypass the `try!()` issue?

Below is the relevant compiler error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:4:20
  |
4 |     let metadata = try!(fs::metadata(path));
  |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected bool, found enum `std::result::Result`
  |
  = note: expected type `bool`
             found type `std::result::Result<_, _>`
  = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate

error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:3:40
  |
3 |   pub fn path_exists(path: &str) -> bool {
  |  ________________________________________^
4 | |     let metadata = try!(fs::metadata(path));
5 | |     assert!(metadata.is_file());
6 | | }
  | |_^ expected (), found bool
  |
  = note: expected type `()`
             found type `bool`
```

Comment: Have you seen [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30555477/try-does-not-compile) about `try!`? Or the [Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/error-handling.html) section on error handing?

Answer (score 212, accepted):

Note that many times you want to do *something* with the file, like read it. In those cases, it makes more sense to just try to open it and deal with the `Result`. This eliminates [a race condition between "check to see if file exists" and "open file if it exists"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use). If all you really care about is if it exists...

#### Rust 1.5+

[`Path::exists`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.exists)... exists:

```
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    println!("{}", Path::new("/etc/hosts").exists());
}
```

[As mental points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32384594/how-to-check-whether-a-path-exists/32384768?noredirect=1#comment95573759_32384768), `Path::exists` simply [calls `fs::metadata` for you](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.32.0/src/libstd/path.rs#L2406-L2408):

> ```
> pub fn exists(&self) -> bool {
>     fs::metadata(self).is_ok()
> }
> ```

#### Rust 1.0+

You can check if the [`fs::metadata`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.metadata.html) method succeeds:

```
use std::fs;

pub fn path_exists(path: &str) -> bool {
    fs::metadata(path).is_ok()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", path_exists("/etc/hosts"));
}
```

Comment: @Juxhin it's often the simple answers that are hardest to find! ^_^

Comment: Indeed. I would understand scenarios where you would want to do more than a validation check but since I'm just getting myself used to language for now I wanted to just slowly expose myself to the standard API as I've never delved into this programming paradigm before. Thanks again :-)

Comment: It is worth mentioning that `Path::exists` is an alias to `fs::metadata(path).is_ok()`

Answer (score 15):

You can use `std::path::Path::is_file`:

```
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
   let b = Path::new("file.txt").is_file();
   println!("{}", b);
}
```

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.is_file