# Check whether a path exists, including CWD?

Tags: rust

(Very similar question, excluding CWD support:
[How to check whether a path exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32384594/how-to-check-whether-a-path-exists))

I want to check whether a file-system paths parent directory - given as string - exists,
also if that parent is the CWD, indicated as "".

In my specific case, I get a local file path as CLI argument,
that points to the output/result file of my software.
The file does not have to exist, but it's parent dir has to exist,
which I check with `Path::new(out_file).parent()?.exists()`.
If `out_file` is for example `"out.txt"`, it's parent will be `""`,
Which will always return `false` for the `exists()` call,
because Rust does not interpret `Path::new("")` as CWD.

Answer (score 0):

credits go to `@chai.t.rex` on the rust discord channel:

```rust
/**
 * Returns the path to the parent dir of the argument, if it has one.
 * We use this rather complex way of doing it,
 * because with a simple `file_path.parent()?.exists()`,
 * we would get `false` in case of `"bla.txt"`,
 * even if CWD is an existing directory.
 */
fn get_parent<P>(file_path: P) -> Option<PathBuf>
where
    P: AsRef<Path>,
{
    let file_path_val = file_path.as_ref();
    let parent = file_path_val.parent()?;
    if parent.components().next().is_none() {
        return current_dir().ok();
    }
    Some(parent.to_owned())
}
```