# Read one level of directory structure

Tags: rust

I am trying to list all of the directories (not recursively) in a directory using Rust. I am mostly following the example code [from the `read_dir`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.read_dir.html) docs, but I am trying to make it simpler since I know what the directory is ahead of time and I don't need to recurse.

I have it down to:

```
for entry in read_dir(Path::new("known-directory")) {
    let path = entry.path();

    if path.is_dir() {
        print!("{}", entry);
    }
}
```

This doesn't work since I get complaints of

> `` no method named `path` found for type `std::fs::ReadDir` in the current scope ``

It seems like `for` is not actually iterating over the entries of `ReadDir`.

I have also tried `try!(read_dir(Path::new("DefinitelyTyped")))` similar to what is in the docs, but this yields

> `` expected (), found enum `std::result::Result` ``

Using `let entry = try!(entry)` does not work either.

Ultimately I would like to push these directory entries to an array, sort it, and JSON-stringify it but of course first I have to be able iterate through the entries properly. How can I do this?

Version: `rustc 1.13.0`
Running with: `cargo 0.13.0`

Comment: Note: using the `try!` macro, or since you are on 1.13 the `?` operator requires the function in which it is invoked to return a `Result`; this is what `expected (), found enum...` is telling you.

Comment: @Shepmaster: If I am getting this right, `read_dir` returns a result, which implements `IntoIterator` yielding the actual `ReadDir` instance, which is what the OP is iterating on instead of the directory entries.

Comment: @MatthieuM. yep

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's read the compiler error messages together!

> ```
> error: no method named `path` found for type `std::fs::ReadDir` in the current scope
>  --> src/main.rs:5:26
>   |
> 5 |         let path = entry.path();
>   |                          ^^^^
> ```

This means that the type of `entry` is a `ReadDir`, but how did that happen? We are supposed to be iterating over a `ReadDir`!

If we look at the [documentation for `read_dir`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.read_dir.html), we can see that it returns a `Result`:

```
pub fn read_dir<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) -> Result<ReadDir>
```

This means that the process of reading a directory can fail, which is entirely believable — what if the directory doesn't exist? However, the presented code doesn't handle that error. It instead passes the `Result` to the `for` loop. `for` loops work by calling `IntoIterator`, and `Result` implements that, yielding the `Ok` case or nothing at all. `Option` has a similar implementation.

So, you added `try!` to the code...

```
for entry in try!(fs::read_dir("/etc"))
```

> ```
> error[E0308]: mismatched types
>  --> src/main.rs:4:18
>   |
> 4 |     for entry in try!(fs::read_dir("/etc")) {
>   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected (), found enum `std::result::Result`
>   |
>   = note: expected type `()`
>   = note:    found type `std::result::Result<_, _>`
>   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate
> ```

As has been [discussed previously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30555477/155423) and is mentioned in the [documentation for `try!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.try.html):

> Because of the early return, `try!` can only be used in functions that return `Result`.

You have to handle the error somehow, and for whatever reason, your current function states that it *cannot fail* — it doesn't return a `Result`! Instead, let's just kill the entire program by panicking by adding `expect` to the call:

```
for entry in fs::read_dir("/etc").expect("I told you this directory exists")
```

(Some people use `unwrap`, but I will **always** advocate for `expect` as it has a higher chance of providing useful information for the poor soul that experiences the eventual failure)

> ```
> error: no method named `path` found for type `std::result::Result<std::fs::DirEntry, std::io::Error>` in the current scope
>  --> src/main.rs:5:26
>   |
> 5 |         let path = entry.path();
>   |                          ^^^^
> ```

Yes, there are even *more* failure cases possible. Specifically, reading each entry may fail for some reason. That's why the `ReadDir` iterator says

```
type Item = Result<DirEntry>
```

Again, your function still states it cannot fail, so we have to panic again:

```
let entry = entry.expect("I couldn't read something inside the directory");
```

> ```
> error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::fs::DirEntry: std::fmt::Display` is not satisfied
>  --> src/main.rs:9:26
>   |
> 9 |             print!("{}", entry);
>   |                          ^^^^^ trait `std::fs::DirEntry: std::fmt::Display` not satisfied
>   |
>   = note: `std::fs::DirEntry` cannot be formatted with the default formatter; try using `:?` instead if you are using a format string
>   = note: required by `std::fmt::Display::fmt`
> ```

As stated well in the error message, change `{}` to `{:?}` because `DirEntry` has no proper way to be formatted for end-users. Programmers can deal with the debugging format.

---

```
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    for entry in fs::read_dir("/etc").expect("I told you this directory exists") {
        let entry = entry.expect("I couldn't read something inside the directory");
        let path = entry.path();

        if path.is_dir() {
            print!("{:?}", entry);
        }
    }
}
```

I'd highly recommend re-reading the [error handling chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/error-handling.html) of [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/). I'd also advocate for basically memorizing the methods and traits implemented for [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) and [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html), seeing as how core they are to the Rust experience.

Here's a version that returns an error from main and uses the try operator (`?`):

```
use std::{error::Error, fs};

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    for entry in fs::read_dir("/etc")? {
        let entry = entry?;
        let path = entry.path();

        if path.is_dir() {
            print!("{:?}", entry);
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this really clears up quite a lot. I didn't know about `expect` vs. `unwrap`.