# Why can't I use the ? operator in my main function on a function that returns an Option?

Tags: rust

Using this file:

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    println!("{}", env::args().nth(3)?);
}
```

I get this error:

```
error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be used in a function that returns `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `std::ops::Try`)
 --> src/main.rs:4:20
  |
4 |     println!("{}", env::args().nth(3)?);
  |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot use the `?` operator in a function that returns `()`
  |
  = help: the trait `std::ops::Try` is not implemented for `()`
  = note: required by `std::ops::Try::from_error`
```

However this is confusing because [`nth` does return `Option`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.nth):

```
fn nth(&mut self, n: usize) -> Option<Self::Item>
```

Am I misunderstanding the documentation or is this a bug?

Comment: You're applying `?` to the result of `nth`, which is different from using it _inside_ it. You're calling `nth`, not implementing it. `main` is the function you're writing it in, which doesn't return `Option`.

Answer (score 10):

The return type of `main` must implement [`std::process::Termination`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/trait.Termination.html)(currently it's an unstable trait). If you look at the end of the documentation, you will see:

```
impl Termination for !
impl Termination for ()
impl Termination for ExitCode
impl<E: Debug> Termination for Result<!, E>
impl<E: Debug> Termination for Result<(), E>
```

If you want to return an `Option` you must implement the trait on it. This is not practical [because you can't implement a trait on foreign type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25413201/155423), so the best solution is to convert `Option<T>` to `Result<T, E>`:

```
use std::env;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<std::error::Error>> {
    println!("{}", env::args().nth(3).ok_or("Missing argument")?);
    Ok(())
}
```

See also:

- [Why do try!() and ? not compile when used in a function that doesn't return Option or Result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30555477/why-do-try-and-not-compile-when-used-in-a-function-that-doesnt-return-opti)

Answer (score 2):

The `?` operator will cause the function containing it to return `None` if the value the `?` is applied to is `None`.

This means you can write

```
fn not_main() -> Option<()> {
    println!("{}", std::env::args().nth(3)?);
    Ok(())
}
```

since `nth` returns an `Option<Item>` and `not_main` returns an `Option<()>`.

However, your `main` does not return an `Option`, hence `?` can't work inside it.

How you work around this will depend on what you want to do in the case of a missing argument. The most brutal solution is to `unwrap` instead - which will cause your code to panic.

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", env::args().nth(3).unwrap())
}
```

An alternative is to match and handle the missing case

```
fn main() {
    match std::env::args().nth(3) {
        Some(ref v) => println!("{}", v),
        None => println!("Missing argument"),
    }
}
```

Since `Option` supports `Debug` you could print the debug version - which will output `None`, or `Some("arg3")`.

```
fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", std::env::args().nth(3));
}
```

Comment: I thought there was a way to return Result from `main` ?

Comment: A better reference for returning Result from main is https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/edition-guide/rust-2018/error-handling-and-panics/question-mark-in-main-and-tests.html

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use `?` on a Option value in main, you probably need to implement you own Option.

In your case, [nothing](https://crates.io/crates/nothing)::[Probably](https://docs.rs/nothing/latest/nothing/enum.Probably.html) is a better Option.

Example (you need nightly toolchain to run it):

```
use nothing::{Nothing, Probably, Something};

fn get_args() -> Probably<Vec<String>> {
    match std::env::args().skip(1).collect::<Vec<String>>() {
        args @ _ if args.len() > 0 => Something(args),
        _ => Nothing,
    }
}

fn main() -> Probably<Vec<String>> {
    let some_args = get_args();

    println!("some_args = {some_args:?}");

    let args = some_args?; // <- it returns here if some_args is Nothing

    println!("args = {args:?}");

    Something(args)
}
```

It works because `Probably` implements `std::process::Termination` so you can return it from you main function. Additionally it implements `std::ops::Try` so you can use `?` on it.