# How to save ndarray in Rust as image?

Tags: image, multidimensional-array, rust

I have ndarray

```rust
let mut a = Array3::<u8>::from_elem((50, 40, 3), 3);
```

and I use image library

```rust
 let mut imgbuf = image::ImageBuffer::new(50, 40);
```

How could I save my ndarray as image ?
If there is better image library then image for this I could use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way is to ensure that the array follows is in standard layout (C-contiguous) with the image dimensions in the order `(height, width, channel)` order (HWC), or in an equivalent memory layout. This is necessary because `image` expects rows to be contiguous in memory.

Then, build a [`RgbImage`](https://docs.rs/image/0.21.2/image/type.RgbImage.html) using the type's [`from_raw`](https://docs.rs/image/0.21.2/image/struct.ImageBuffer.html#method.from_raw) function.

```rust
use image::RgbImage;
use ndarray::Array3;

fn array_to_image(arr: Array3<u8>) -> RgbImage {
    assert!(arr.is_standard_layout());

    let (height, width, _) = arr.dim();
    let raw = arr.into_raw_vec();

    RgbImage::from_raw(width as u32, height as u32, raw)
        .expect("container should have the right size for the image dimensions")
}
```

Example of use:

```rust
let mut array: Array3<u8> = Array3::zeros((200, 250, 3)); // 250x200 RGB

for ((x, y, z), v) in array.indexed_iter_mut() {
    *v = match z {
        0 => y as u8,
        1 => x as u8,
        2 => 0,
        _ => unreachable!(),
    };
}

let image = array_to_image(array);
image.save("out.png")?;
```

The output image:

[image: the output image: a gradient over the red and green channels]

---

Below are a few related helper functions, in case they are necessary.

Ndarrays can be converted to standard layout by calling the method [`as_standard_layout`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.13.0/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.as_standard_layout), available since version 0.13.0. Before this version, you would need to collect each array element into a vector and rebuild the array, like so:

```rust
fn to_standard_layout<A, D>(arr: Array<A, D>) -> Array<A, D>
where
    A: Clone,
    D: Dimension,
{
    let v: Vec<_> = arr.iter().cloned().collect();
    let dim = arr.dim();
    Array::from_shape_vec(dim, v).unwrap()
}
```

Moreover, converting an ndarray in the layout `(width, height, channel)` to `(height, width, channel)` is also possible by swapping the first two axes and making the array C-contiguous afterwards:

```rust
fn wh_to_hw(mut arr: Array3<u8>) -> Array3<u8> {
    arr.swap_axes(0, 1);

    arr.as_standard_layout().to_owned()
}
```

Comment: Is this fast? Would it be faster than manipulating with pixels using for cycle without using ndarray? Like this:  for (x, y, pixel) in imgbuf.enumerate_pixels_mut() {
              let (r, g, b) = some_math(x,y) }
            *pixel = image::Rgb([r as u8, g as u8, b as u8]); imgbuf.save(format!("image.png" )).unwrap();

Comment: @user3048747 Right. Please see my edit. I have replaced the input with an owned array, so that the raw vector can be reused for the `RgbImage`. As long as the array is already in standard layout and the 3rd axis matches the expected RGB channels, this is a zero-copy operation and is just about as fast as it can be.

Comment: I've tried but received `borrow of moved value: arr` error and some others.

Comment: The last question: I have `cannot use the ? operator in a function that returns ()`. When I remove it everything compails, but with warning that `this Result may be an Err variant, which should be handled` Why is this happening?

Comment: Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30555477/1233251). When code examples use `?`, it is implicit that they sit in a function returning a `Result`.

Comment: I've found that this code isn't quite well. If using none square array (f.e. 300 x 200 px) it gives artifacts in image. As I'v understood the problem is in converting from ndarray to raw vec and then to image. But I didn't manage to find solution for this

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, the answer has been updated again. It happens that image libraries usually expect rows to be contiguous in memory, but an ndarray with dimensions `(width, height, channels)` is actually column contiguous (pixel-wise). The image needs to be in standard layout with the image dimensions in the order `(height, width, channels)`.

Comment: How would this be adapted to support RGBA?