# Return type error in an async fn: expected (), found enum `std::result::Result`

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I wrote a simple method to see in which order items that were inserted in the `DelayQueue` in Tokio are returned. `DelayQueue` has a method `poll_expired` which takes a `task::Context` as argument. I want to call `poll_explained` inside a loop until all `Delays` instances in the `DelayQueue` timed out and are returned by `poll_expired` and use the `Context` provided by the Tokio runtime. To do this, I use a function `poll_fn`:

```
use std::vec::Vec;
use tokio::time::delay_queue::Key;
use tokio::time::{DelayQueue, Duration, Error};

use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::task::{Context, Poll};

/// Creates a new future wrapping around a function returning [`Poll`].
fn poll_fn<T, F>(f: F) -> PollFn<F>
where
    F: FnMut(&mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<T>,
{
    PollFn { f }
}
```

where `PollFn` implements `Future`:

```
/// Future for the [`poll_fn`] function.
struct PollFn<F> {
    f: F,
}

impl<T, F> Future for PollFn<F>
where
    F: FnMut(&mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<T>,
{
    type Output = T;

    fn poll(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<T> {
        (&mut self.f)(cx)
    }
}
```

Then I create my function which batches all the expired `Delays` and delegate it to `poll_fn`:

```
macro_rules! ready {
    ($e:expr $(,)?) => {
        match $e {
            std::task::Poll::Ready(t) => t,
            std::task::Poll::Pending => return std::task::Poll::Pending,
        }
    };
}

fn poll_expired_batch(
    dq: &mut DelayQueue<u32>,
    cx: &mut Context<'_>,
) -> Poll<Result<Vec<(u32, u64)>, Error>> {
    let mut expired_keys: Vec<(u32, u64)> = Vec::new();
    while let Some(res) = ready!(dq.poll_expired(cx)) {
        let exp = res?;
        let data = exp.get_ref();
        expired_keys.push((data.inner, data.when));
    }
    Poll::Ready(Ok(expired_keys));
}

async fn poll_batch(dq: &mut DelayQueue<u32>) -> Result<Vec<(u32, u64)>, Error> {
    poll_fn(|cx| poll_expired_batch(dq, cx)).await;
}
```

Then inside the `tokio::main` block I have the following code:

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut dq: DelayQueue<u32> = DelayQueue::new();
    let mut keys: Vec<Key> = Vec::new();
    (0..10).map(|i| keys.push(dq.insert(i, Duration::new(1, 0))));
    println!("Insertion order");
    for key in keys {
        println("Key {} inserted");
    }
    let keys_returned = (poll_batch(&mut dq).await)?;
}
```

I get the following error and I wasn't able to find out what it means and how to fix it:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<impl core::future::future::Future as core::future::future::Future>::Output == std::result::Result<std::vec::Vec<(u32, u64)>, tokio::time::error::Error>`
  --> examples/delay_q.rs:75:51
   |
75 | async fn poll_batch(dq : &mut DelayQueue<u32>) -> Result<Vec<(u32, u64)>, Error>{
   |                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected (), found enum `std::result::Result`
   |
   = note: expected type `()`
              found type `std::result::Result<std::vec::Vec<(u32, u64)>, tokio::time::error::Error>`
   = note: the return type of a function must have a statically known size
```

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Notably, there have been recent incompatible releases of the `tokio` and `futures` crates, so it's vitally important to include that information (and that information should always be included when asking a question in any context, anyway).

Comment: Remove the semicolon from `poll_fn(|cx| poll_expired_batch(dq, cx)).await;`

Comment: [`PollFn`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.1/futures/future/struct.PollFn.html) already exists, there's no reason to rewrite it.

Comment: `println` is not a function. Please ensure that the code you provide matches the errors you are asking about.

Comment: See also [Why do try!() and ? not compile when used in a function that doesn't return Option or Result?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30555477/155423)

Comment: [`ready!`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.1/futures/macro.ready.html) already exists, there's no reason to rewrite it.