# Why get method is not returning a Response object in reqwest?

Tags: rust, reqwest

I'm trying to replicate an example from reqwest [documentation](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.9.18/reqwest/fn.get.html). Here is the example:

```
let body = reqwest::get("https://www.rust-lang.org")?
.text()?;
```

After I have added the `reqwest = "0.10.10"` line in the file Cargo.toml, I add the following code in my `main.rs` file:

```rust
extern crate reqwest;

fn main() {
    let body = reqwest::get("https://www.rust-lang.org")?.text()?;
    println!("body = {:?}", body);
}
```

This code don't compile and returns the following error:

```
cannot use the `?` operator in a function that returns `()`
```

I'm a bit surprised with this behaviour since my code is almost *ipsis litteris* the documentation code.

I think that `?` works only on Response objects, so I checked which object the `get` method is returning:

```rust
extern crate reqwest;

fn print_type_of<T>(_: &T) {
    println!("{}", std::any::type_name::<T>())
}

fn main() {
    let body = reqwest::get("https://www.rust-lang.org");
    print_type_of(&body);
}
```

output:

```
core::future::from_generator::GenFuture<reqwest::get<&str>::{{closure}}
```

I mean, why I'm not getting an Response object instead, just like the documentation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do try!() and ? not compile when used in a function that doesn't return Option or Result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30555477/why-do-try-and-not-compile-when-used-in-a-function-that-doesnt-return-opti)

Comment: Thanks. But no. It doesn't. I don't have issues with `?` operator. I want to understand why I am receiving an object other than what, according to the documentation, would be expected.

Comment: The "cannot use the `?` operator in a function that returns `()`" is because of this issue. `let body = reqwest::get("https://www.rust-lang.org")?.text()?;` is using a bunch of `?`, and the error is telling you that you are using `?` in a place where it isn't allowed, because `main` does not return a `Result`.

Comment: The documentation says that `get` should be of the type `pub fn get<T: IntoUrl>(url: T) -> Result<Response>`, while I'm getting `core::future::from_generator::GenFuture<reqwest::get<&str>::{{closure}}`. The operator `?` would work perfectly if I was getting the right type of object instead. The problem is not `?` is the fact that `get` is not a response object in my case.

Comment: You're right, there's actually two different problems, the one you mentioned and the one I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two separate issues here tripping you up.

The documentation that you've linked to is for `reqwest` version  `0.9.18`, but you've installed version `0.10.10`. If you look at [the docs for `0.10.10`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.10.10/reqwest/index.html), you will see that the snippet you use is

```
let body = reqwest::get("https://www.rust-lang.org")
    .await?
    .text()
    .await?;

println!("body = {:?}", body);
```

or more likely in your case, since you have not mentioned having an async runtime, [the `blocking` docs](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.10.10/reqwest/blocking/index.html)

```
let body = reqwest::blocking::get("https://www.rust-lang.org")?
    .text()?;

println!("body = {:?}", body);
```

Note that when you try to use this one, you will *still* get that

> cannot use the `?` operator in a function that returns `()`

and you will need to set a return type on `main` like

```
fn main() -> Result<(), reqwest::Error> {
```

See [Why do try!() and ? not compile when used in a function that doesn't return Option or Result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30555477/why-do-try-and-not-compile-when-used-in-a-function-that-doesnt-return-opti) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read this section of the Rust docs: https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/error-handling-and-panics/index.html

In short, `?` simply passes the error from a `Result` further up the call stack via an implicit `return`. As such the function in which you use the `?` operator must return the same type as the function on which `?` was used.

Answer (score 0):

Each response is wrapped in a `Result` type which you can unwrap.

```
use reqwest;
    
    #[tokio::main]
    async fn main() {
    
        let response = reqwest::get("https://www.rust-lang.org")
            .await
            .unwrap()
            .text()
            .await;
        println!("{:?}", response);
    }
```

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "request"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"
reqwest = "0.10.10"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
reqwest = { version = "0.11", features = ["json"] } # reqwest with JSON parsing support
futures = "0.3" # for our async / await blocks
tokio = { version = "1.12.0", features = ["full"] } # for async runtime
```